# how to choose the order that tests are run

Tags: python, pytest, playwright

i have multiple tests that require the database to be populated (ie, a test to change an organisations address, upload a logo, a test to delete an org, etc). since i need an organisation for all tests, im forced to put them in a certain order (the test that creates the organisation first, and the test that deletes it last).

heres an example of why this is an issue. i have 2 separate files, one for `org_admin` tests and the other for `super_admin` tests. i need to run the `create_org` test in the `test_super_admin` file. then the `update_org` test from the `test_org_admin` file. then go back to the `test_super_admin` file to run `delete_org`. this doesnt work as the tests are in this order `create_org`, `delete_org`, `update_org`.

example of the file structure:

```
file - test_super_admin
-- test - create_org
-- test - delete_org

file - test_org_admin
-- test - update_org
```

how can i make this work without putting all tests in one file and putting them in a specific order?

thank you.

Comment: Don't do that. Use a database fixture to set up the required state for a test suite.

Comment: Test should be independent of each other. They should run alone, in any order and (pro version) in parallel without problems.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, your tests should be independent and indeed this can be achieved with database fixtures. One way to achieve this and worked really well for me is by using `testcontainers`: https://github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-python.

A fixture might look like this in `pytest` with, in my case, a Postgress database:

```
@pytest.fixture(scope="module", name="session_for_db_in_testcontainer")
def db_engine():
    """
    Creates testcontainer with Postgres db
    """
    pg_container = PostgresContainer('postgres:latest')
    pg_container.start()

    # Fireup the SQLModel engine with the uri of the container
    db_engine = create_engine(pg_container.get_connection_url())
    sqlmodel_metadata.create_all(db_engine)

    with Session(db_engine) as session_for_db_in_testcontainer:
        # add some rows to start, for test get requests and posting existing data
        add_data_to_test_db(database_input_path, session_for_db_in_testcontainer)
        yield session_for_db_in_testcontainer

    # Will be executed after the last test
    session_for_db_in_testcontainer.close()
    pg_container.stop()
```

Like this during the test run a (Postgres) DB is created it only runs during a session, module or function depending on the scope of the fixture. If you want, you can add test data to the db as well like in the example.

Comment: Thank you. I should have mentioned in my question that my tests are hitting a website hosted on a server. I don't think this solution will work in that case will it?